# Is the density of 1's in the Fibonacci word uniform?

Tags: limits-and-convergence, symbolic-dynamics, combinatorics-on-words

The [Fibonacci word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word) is the limit of the sequence of words starting with  $0$ and satisfying rules $0 \to 01, 1 \to 0$. Equivalently, it is obtained from the recursion $S_n= S_{n-1}S_{n-2}$ under initial conditions $S_0 = 0, S_1 = 01$. Let us denote this Fibonacci word as $f_k\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb Z_+}$.

We define the Fibonacci subshift $\Omega$ as the set of all two-sided right limits of the Fibonacci word. More precisely, we extend our Fibonacci word to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb Z}$ by defining $\{f_j\}_{j=-\infty}^0$ arbitrarily, and define $(\mathcal Tf)_k=f_{k+1}$. The Fibonacci subshift $\Omega$ is then the set of limit points of $\{\mathcal T^n  f\}_{n=0}^\infty$ under the product topology on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

It is easy to show that the ratio of zeroes to ones in the Fibonacci word is $\varphi$, the golden ratio. Equivalently, the density of ones in the Fibonacci word (that is, the ratio of the number of ones in a subword to the length of the subword) tends to $\frac{1}{\varphi^2}$. I would like to know if this is true uniformly. That is,

> Is the following true for a.e.  $\omega\in\Omega$? Given any
> $c\in\mathbb Z$,  $$\lim_{m\to\infty}
> \sum_{j=c-m}^{c+m}\frac{\omega_j}{2m+1}=\frac{1}{\varphi^2} $$
> uniformly in $c$.

I also suspect this might be true for every $\omega\in\Omega$, not just a.e.

Comment: Another answer that the one by David Speyer below is to say that the Fibonacci word is the sequence of 0's and 1's obtained from the orbit of 0 under the dynamical system $R_\phi(t)=t+\phi\bmod 1$, where $\phi$ is the golden mean; $I_0=[0,\phi-1)$ and $I_1=[\phi-1,1)$ (so that the sequence of 0's and 1's records the order in which the order visits the intervals $I_0$ and $I_1$). The uniformity you are asking for follows from unique ergodicity of irrational circle rotations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. By Proposition 2.1.10 in [Lothaire, Algebraic Combinatorics on Words](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Auteurs/aaaDivers/Lothaire%20-%20Algebraic%20Combinatorics%20On%20Words.pdf), if $u$ is any substring of the Fibonacci word then 
$$\left| \frac{\mbox{number of $1$'s in $u$}}{\mbox{length of $u$}} - \frac{1}{\phi^2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\mbox{length of $u$}}.$$
Any length $n$ substring of any $\omega \in \Omega$ is also a length $n$ substring of the Fibonacci word, so the same bound applies to it.